# Multiple Conditional statements in LINQ

Tags: linq

Is this possible to do in LINQ, this wouldn;t compile however this is the result am trying to achieve.

I know I can filter this prior to union statement, curious to know if this is supported or not.

```
var _tickers = (from _position in positions_
                      where _position.Ticker_PositionQuote.PropertyValue != string.Empty
                      select _position.Ticker_PositionQuote.PropertyValue)
        .Union(
          from _position in positions_
          where _position.AssetClassLevel2.PropertyValue.ToUpper() == "EQUITY OPTIONS"
          and _position.Ticker_PositionUnderlyerQuote.PropertyValue != string.Empty
          select _position.Ticker_PositionUnderlyerQuote.PropertyValue);
```

Thanks,

Raul Dsouza

Comment: If you are just looking for this "and", this is a way too complex piece of code. Try giving minimal examples in the future =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for a way to implement this "and" statement. Please correct me if I am wrong.

To get the result of

```
from item in collection
where condition1 "and" condition2
```

you can use either

```
from item in collection
where condition1 && condition2
```

or

```
from item in collection
where condition1 
where condition2
```

The first method will probably be faster.